Short story in which an alien rewards spare parts with new teeth
I read the story many years ago as one of several others in a SF short story collection book, probably in the 70s.
An alien comes to visit an elderly man at his house and asks for some electrical parts in order to repair its ship. The guy eventually helps him by allowing him to harvest the inner components of his television device. The alien replaces the electronic stuff with a kind of wire loop and the TV works great. After the alien left, the guy realises, that he is getting new teeth growing.
I would like to know the title and author of that story.

In roughly which year or decade did you read this? Did you mean to say the 70s rather than the 70th?

I've read this...hmmm, need to think. Part of me says a Howard Fast story.

I meant 70s, not 70th. Thanks for the hint.

I had a look on a bunch of Howard Fast stories and could not find it. From my perspective it probably is not by Howard Fast.
